# Deleted emails automatically re-appear in original folders of an Office365 email account

Tags: exchange, office365

I have an O365 email with problem that I cannot delete email in any folder like Inbox, Sent Item, Deleted, etc... After I delete one or more emails, those deleted emails automatically re-appear at the original place. Problem happens to delete action only, and I still able to move emails from one folder to another.

Some settings I got via Exchange Admin

- It's not a shared mailbox
- Litigation hold is Off
- Mailbox archive is on (1.29GB / 100GB)
- Mailbox size 80GB / 100GB

I'd like to solve the problem before the mailbox reaches its limit 100GB.
Hope someone can give me some hints to fix this.

Comment: Open a case on Microsoft in case you are right to know - you pay them, remember that?! :-)

Comment: Please check if the below answer is helpful to you, if your problem has been fixed, you could mark the best answer or share your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Do other users in your organization have the same issue?

Where did you delete emails? Outlook desktop, OWA or other clients?

Are these deleted emails still in the mailbox folders if you access OWA? Do you see  these emails if you run the following command in Exchange Online PowerShell?

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity <Mailbox Identity> -SearchQuery 'Subject:"<Subject>" AND From:"<Sender>" AND To:"<Recipient>"' -EstimateResultOnly

Search-Mailbox -Identity <Mailbox Identity> -SearchQuery 'Subject:"<Subject>" AND From:"<Sender>" AND To:"<Recipient>"' -TargetMailbox <Mailbox to receive the search report> -TargetFolder Test
```

The first command will estimate the search result, the second one will create a target folder in the target mailbox and send a search report to this folder(The report includes the searched emails.).

More details about the search cmdlet: **[Search-Mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/search-mailbox?view=exchange-ps)**

If you didn't see these deleted emails on other clients after being deleted, I think it may be a sync issue(Perhaps some network issues), try to manually update folders or recreate profiles and see if there is any difference.

Besides, you can also try running the following commands to delete emails(**Please note**: To avoid losing important emails, you need make sure the search query condition is accurate and use the second command to check if emails are the ones you want to delete.):

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity <Mailbox Identity> -SearchQuery 'Subject:"<Subject>" AND From:"<Sender>" AND To:"<Recipient>"' -DeleteContent
```